# webpack --devtool didn't work. How can i fix that?

Tags: javascript, webpack, package.json

I was following a ReactJS tutorial on Youtube and i stuck at while running "npm start" because there was an error on terminal:

[webpack-cli] Error: Option '-d, --devtool ' argument missing
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options

webpack.config.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import { resolve } from 'path';

var DIST_DIR = resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    debug: true,
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    modules: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

export default config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactjs-tutorials-academind-youtube",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "I learn ReactJS on Academind Tutorials on Youtube :)",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/khye1/ReactJS-Academind-Tutorial.git"
  },
  "author": "MeoCon22",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/khye1/ReactJS-Academind-Tutorial/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/khye1/ReactJS-Academind-Tutorial#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

Link tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uextYhQGP6k&list=PL55RiY5tL51oyA8euSROLjMFZbXaV7skS&index=2

Thank you so much. <3

I tried to run "npm start" but there was an error. How can i fix that?

Comment: Just a tip: the tutorial you linked was from 6yrs ago. For a first timer, this could be so much unecessary problems. I recommend recent tutorials with webpack 5. I'm not saying the tutorial is useless or anything but it could be alot easier if you follow tutorials with webpack 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your script to this. `"scripts": { "start": "webpack serve --open", "build": "webpack" }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you explain more details? I still stuck.

Comment: I noticed you are following a tutorial from webpack 4, I guess? There've been many changes since then. It would be exhausting to address every single details, not that it's impossible with all due respect. My point is learn webpack 5 first if you are just getting to know it for the first time. Then you can study the legacy ones later. Peace...